# Playing a game from a secondary HDD

Tags: fallout-new-vegas, hard-drive

So I have been trying to play Fallout New Vegas from my secondary hard drive. When I upgraded my hard disk I left the old one with all the data still in it and am using it as a secondary. When I try to run the game it tells me to install even though all the files are there on the E: drive. Is there an option I have so that the games looks for the files on the E: drive instead of the  C:?

Comment: Did you install it to the second hard drive, or did you just copy it over?  If you just copied it, that usually doesn't work, due to the installer adding registry entries and other fun stuff.

Comment: The secondary hard drive used to be a primary hard drive. When it was my primary I had installed the game. Now its my secondary HDD and the game files (along with all my other files) are still there.

Comment: With the new primary, though, you had to install Windows, right?  That means those registry entries that were originally created aren't accessible.  You'll probably have to reinstall the game onto E:, and then it should work, I bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, the game was originally installed on the primary Windows hard drive, but then was relegated to secondary status.  In those cases, even though the game was installed, the extraneous configuration changes the installer made are no longer accessible to the new installation of Windows, and it doesn't know what to do with them.

Your best bet in these cases is to reinstall (or, if the installer allows, repair) the game, over top of the old files.  That will refresh the configuration changes, and allow you to properly play your game again.